# How can I know which line in my code that produces a certain output?

Tags: r

Sometimes my code, that I run via the terminal in MacOS, will print warnings or just output things that I didn't expect it to do (such as a data frame). Can I somehow, together with these outputs, get an indication of which lines in my code that are producing them?

Comment: Just reading the code should tell you.  If you are using user defined functions, good to use `return` statements to ensure you get from the functions what you intend.  Also good to post some sample code here.

Comment: "that I run via the terminal in MacOS" Don't do that. Install RStudio and use scripts. Or use another IDE ... Even Rgui would do.

Comment: @SteveM Regarding sample code: Just imagine a script with a couple of thousand lines where some line throws a warning. I might use functions from libraries that I haven't written myself meaning that I don't know what type of errors they might throw. In that case, I won't be able to figure out which line is the problem simply by reading the code.

Comment: @Roland Would RStudio (or some other IDE) show me where the warning comes from?

Comment: You could try rerun specific lines easily and see which part if your code produces the unexpected output. TBH, unexpected output isn't a frequent issue for me...

Comment: @Roland I could, and I just did, but it's a huge waste of time compared to just having the output tell me that the warning in question comes from line 2435. It's a frequent issue for me unfortunately.